# Template for use with Outlook 2010 t enable creation of multiple PST's for many users on one system

Tags: scripting, outlook, template

This is probably not something many people would have a need for but at this company where there is a large turnover, every user has to have IT create their account on a laptop.  Even when recycling, the need is still the same.  Each account has the same incoming and outgoing mail-server, the same incoming and outgoing ports, the same other misc. settings like days to hold mail (14.. the default) and delete from server when deleted from inbox (yes.. Not the default).

Pretty much the whole thing is exactly the same except for the username and password.  After filling out 10 or so a day, it gets to be where you would think there must be a way to create a prefilled template that only needs the username and password changed.  Or a script that would fill in the fields that stay the same in every case.

If anyone has already solved this problem, please pass along the knowledge

Comment: You probably want to look at using the OCT in combination with a PRF for Outlook. - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179097.aspx - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179062(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Will do.  MS Exchange is a possibility but the owners have to agree to it and so far they wont

Answer (score 0):

Use Exchange: auto-configuration, retention policies, etc; all configurable (and scriptable).

The time saved messing with this stuff will pay for the Licensing quickly.